# unterminated `s' command -- running sed from a .sh script, to replace a string that includes a "="

Tags: sed

I am really struggling with a very silly but complex type of issue while running `sed` from a `.sh` script, to replace a string that includes a `=`.

My command, `sed -i 's/^host=.*/host=myhost1/' /opt/file.txt` runs very well while I execute from terminal.

However, while I try this command CMD from a .sh file it shows me error like below:

```
CMD="sed -i 's/^host=.*/host=myhost1/' /opt/file.txt"
```

The error I get is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Looking at the error, I could find it is the problem with `=` in the search/replace strings. I tried escaping this, and many other options but could not succeed. Even when I remove the `=` from the strings, it works well from the .sh as well.

Comment: Whats the purpose of CMD="sed -i 's/^host=.*/host=myhost1/' /opt/file.txt"? You can run the command from the script without assigning it to a variable..

Comment: Post the whole script

Comment: bash faq 50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

When you type `CMD="sed -i 's/^host=.*/host=myhost1/' /opt/file.txt"`, you are using `"` (double quotes), asking the shell to interpret special characters like `*`.

It will replace `.*` with a list of all the files in the current directory that begin with a `.`, thus confusing `sed`.

Make the `*` unspecial with a backslash `\*`. Also to `echo "$CMD"` to see the filenames.

Comment: No, it won't. Double quotes allow variable expansion and command substitution, but not globbing.